# "in a 4:1:3 ratio" in German

Tags: idiomaticity

I'd say:

> Die drei Ingredienzien müssen **im Verhältnis von 4:1:3** vermischt werden.

... to express the idea of:

> Mix them **in the ratio of 4:1:3**. --- {numbers **following** the word "ratio"}
>
> {or}: Mix them **in a 4:1:3 ratio**. --- {numbers **preceding** the word "ratio"}

Question: Is it possible in German to have numbers precede the word "Verhältnis" in a similar way to "in a 4:1:3 ratio"?

The equivalent expressions in French, Italian, Spanish, Russian etc all take the form of "a noun corresponding to *ratio* + numbers", just like "in the ratio of 4:1:3". Can it go either way in German?

Comment: The word "Verhältnis" just expresses well what you want to say. The more natural expression is to use it _before_ the numbers.

Comment: I want to point out that a ratio is always a quotient of **two** quantities and not of three. Also mathematically, your expression with three quantities doesn't make sense, because it is not scale invariant anymore. For example, 4:1:3 = 4:3, but if you double each quantity, the result is 8:2:6 =  2:3 instead of 4:3.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Strictly speaking, yes. But don't we just use the noun "ratio" anyway, if nothing else, for lack of a better term for comparing three quantities? By the way, I'm afraid I don't quite follow what you mean by your 2nd sentence.  The idea I want to convey here is: "A:B:C = 4:1:3", in other words, "A and C are four and three times as much as B respectively".

Comment: Not only strictly speaking! Ratios are used to express that the quotient of two quantities remains constant when the amounts are scaled. If the ratio of water and flour is 4 ml : 3 g, then water has to sclae the same way as flour does, e.g. 8 ml : 6 g. This property of scale invariance is not fulfilled with three quantities, because division is not an associative operation (4 ml : 1 g : 3 g is not equal to 8 ml : 2 g : 6 g). Of course, you could use two ratios for three quantities to express what you want.

Comment: You should usually translate _ingredient_ by _Zutat_.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich There is a difference in usage in a mathematical or chemical context. In chemistry it is valid to use 4/1/3 to express a mixture of three solvents.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich 4:1:3 is not 4:3. You are confusing it with mathematical division. This is not the correct context.

Comment: @Gerhardh I am not confusing it with division, a ratio **is** division or, more precisely, a quotient of two quantities (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verh%C3%A4ltnis). Furthermore, it is a general concept used in all sorts of disciplines. The interpretation of what a ratio is does not depend on the discipline it is used in. The ratio 4:3 means the same in chemistry as it does in physics, in engineering, or in baking a cake.

Comment: @Björn The Wikipedia article is incomplete. It is missing the link to https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verh%C3%A4ltnisformel.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich: "because division is not an associative operation" - I don't think it is useful to interpret a ratio like "4:1:3" as an arithmetical expression made up of divisions. The common interpretation seems to be closer to a linear equation: ["Mix a ratio of grapefruit to orange juice to lemon juice to lemonade (...) 2:4:1:3" to create Tangerine Dream.](http://www.primaryresources.co.uk/maths/pdfs/tangerine_dream_recipe_ratio.pdf) is equivalent to "2 units of grapefruit + 4 units of orange juice + 1 unit of lemon juice + 3 units of lemonade = 1 (something of) Tangerine Dream".

Answer (score 2):

Both variants are possible:

> Die drei Ingredienzien müssen im Verhältnis (von) vier zu eins zu drei vermischt werden.
>
> Die drei Ingredienzien müssen im Vier-zu-eins-zu-drei-Verhältnis vermischt werden.

Please note the *Durchkoppelung* with hyphens in the second case, because the phrase becomes a compound word in that case.

Comment: No Capitalization of the "v" in "vier-zu-....." ?

Comment: Hi. Does this hyphenated compound-ish phrasing sound just as idiomatic?

Comment: @Beta: You are right, it has to be capitalized. I think this is one of the cases where capitalization stops to look right, because *zu* should not be capitialized in any case, *eins* and *drei* could, and *Verhältnis* must. It just looks ugly.

Comment: Compound nouns are always idiomatic in German.